# in ruby how do you do you map a nested hash tree but skipping the first element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to ignore the first element of my hash tree as it has a different presentation and just map all elements minus the first one. This way my recursive function would work. So in my comments.map loop I would like to ignore the first element or delete it.

```
    def horizontal_tree_for(comments)
        comments.map do |comment, nested_comments|


       entry(comment) + 
          (nested_comments.size > 0 ?          
              content_tag(:div, horizontal_tree_for(nested_comments), class: "branch") +
            "</div>"

          : "</div>")



    end.join.html_safe
  end

def entry(comment)

  "<div class='entry'><span class='label'> #{comment.name} </span>"

end
```

Comment: You don't need "Ruby" in the title because it is a tag. Also, fix "do you do you" and delete "tree" (a "hash" is a Ruby object; "hash trees" have no meaning in Ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ignore the first comment at every nested level

Replace

```
    comments.map do |comment, nested_comments|
```

with

```
    comments.drop(1).map do |comment, nested_comments|
```

## Ignore the first comment of first level only

Just call

```
horizontal_tree_for(root_comments.drop(1))
```

and don't change anything in your method.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main choices:

- `map` from an array comprised of all but the first key-value pair of the given hash, and then operate on that array; or
- build a new array.

Suppose

```
h = { :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3 }
```

@Eric gives a good way of mapping from an array derived from the hash:

```
h.drop(1).map { |k,v| <your code> }
```

as

```
h.drop(1)
  #=> [[:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

To build a new array:

```
h.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |((k,v),ndx),a|
  next if ndx.zero?
  a << <your code, using k and v>
end
```